# Invalid operator in sequences

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$V_n = n! + 2$

$n \ge 1$

Find $V_3$.

I am just wondering what does the "!" operator after "$n$" mean?

Comment: Probably factorial; $n! = n(n - 1)(n - 2) \cdots 3\cdot 2$. In particular, $4! = 4\cdot 3\cdot 2 = 24$.

Comment: @T.Bongers thanks man

Answer (score 1):

It means [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) which can be defined as $\displaystyle n! = \prod_{k = 1}^n k = n \cdot (n - 1) \cdot (n - 2) \cdots 2 \cdot 1$.

As for your original problem $$V_3 = 3! + 2 = 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 + 2 = 6 + 2 = 8.$$